# Does reviving a mercenary resume his mission?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I am currently questing for mercenarys. The first mission was succesful, the new merc died on his mission thogh.

If i revive him does he continue the mission he had before or is he back at the camp and ill hav to assingn him a new one?

Comment: I can't find anything "official" mentioning it.  But in my experience (pre v2.5) a revived merc had to restart and did not pick up where it left off.  I usually save my rubies now though and bury the mercs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came around a merc that i thought was worth saving, when i revived him he continued his mission so thats the answer.